# Creating aspnet_membership table, need script please

Tags: asp.net-membership

Does anyone out there have a create script for aspnet_membership table?

I found a data structure for it on MS site but cannot find a script to create it anywhere on the web.

Many thanks in advance

J

Comment: Any progress on this one? also, you should upvote and accept answers that help you solve your problems. This is the way you show appreciation for the time people take to help you. Welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aspnet_regsql` can emit the script for you using the correct options.

a basic example:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -S server -d database -E -ed
```

The advantage to generating the script is that you can specify things like the schema to use and the features that you need and it will customize and compile a single script.

No need to cobble one together and the inherent risks involved.

Run it with `/?` to get a usage listing.

Answer (score 1):

The script is installed with the .NET framework. Look for it here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallMembership.sql

Note that this script asumes that InstallCommon.sql (found in the same dir) was run first.